# Handling infinite loop in implementation Pushdown Automaton (PDA)

Tags: automata, parsers

I've got a basic implementation of a Pushdown Automaton which recursively checks the rules of a grammar in CNF to find whether a given input string is accepted or not, and it can also count the number of possible derivations of that string.

My problems lie when the grammar has rules which could create infinite loops, e.g. $X \rightarrow X X$ or two sets of rules like:

$X \rightarrow Y Z$

$Y \rightarrow X A$

The code will just continue replacing the variable with itself which obviously leads to infinite recursion.

I'm unsure of how this can be handled in the code, as it could be the case that the same rule does need to be applied many times and then stopped, like in the case of the string $xxxxxxxxxxxx$ where we have the rules

$X \rightarrow X X$

$X \rightarrow x$

How can the code detect an infinite loop and then try all possibilities before breaking out of it by starting to use a new rule rather than the recursive one?

My thinking was that I can allow it to recurse up to the number of characters in the input string and try all possibilities of that, or just somehow calculating all potential combinations of the multiple $X$ rules in the above example and introducing some artificial limit on the number of combinations so it doesn't do too many. This just seems a little impractical to me.

Is there any more systematic way of handling non-determinism like this in code? Thank you.

Comment: [On the translation of languages from left to right](https://web.archive.org/web/20120315152151/http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/cs48/mxcom/doc/knuth65.pdf) (Knuth, 1965)

Comment: The usual approach is to convert the grammar into a form which doesn't exhibit such behavior.